# How to add tracking number programmatically for shipments in magento 2.3?

Tags: custom, magento2.3.2, shipment-tracking, programatically

I want to add the tracking numbers only for created shipment.
I tried below approach and getting an error.

> We cannot create an empty shipment.

How can i add only the tracking number programmatically.

```
$orderNumber = '000000001';
$order = $this->orderFactory->loadByIncrementId($orderNumber);
if($order->hasInvoices()){

$shipment = $this->orderModel->toShipment($order);

foreach ($order->getAllItems() AS $orderItem) {

if (!$orderItem->getQtyToShip() || $orderItem->getIsVirtual()) {
                    continue;
                }
    $qtyShipped = $orderItem->getQtyToShip();

    $shipmentItem = $this->orderModel->itemToShipmentItem($orderItem)->setQty($qtyShipped);

    $shipment->addItem($shipmentItem);

  }

$shipment->register();
            $shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
try {

      $trackingIds = array(
         '0'=>array('carrier_code'=>'fedex','title' => 'Federal Express','number'=>'3131331230'),
         '1'=>array('carrier_code'=>'ups','title' => 'UPS Ground','number'=>'1312312')
                );
foreach ($trackingIds as $trackingId) { 
       $data = array(
            'carrier_code' => $trackingId['carrier_code'],
             'title' => $trackingId['title'],
             'number' => $trackingId['number'],
         );
         $track = $this->trackFactory->create()->addData($data);
         $shipment->addTrack($track)->save(); 

         $shipment->addTrack($track);
         $this->shipmentRepository->save($shipment);

     }
$shipment->save();
$shipment->getOrder()->save();

// Send email
$this->_shipmentNotifier->notify($shipment);
$shipment->save();
enter code here
```